# Save the changes after uploaded a new image after refreshing the page

Tags: php, sql

I want to upload a new image replace with the old one and save the changes permently but after refreshing the my page int he browser itihas shown the old image not the new the one.how can i slove this issue??

here the code of uploading the image in my php file:

```
 <div><form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="file1">

         <input type="submit" name="submit100" value="upload">
        </form>
      <?php
      error_reporting(0); 

      if(isset($_POST['submit100'])){ 
      $con =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login"); 
      $filename=$_FILES["file1"]["name"];
      $tempname=$_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"];
      $folder="upload/".$filename;

      move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder);



    echo"<img src='$folder' height='625' width='800'>";
      $sql=mysqli_query( $con,"INSERT INTO  `picture`(pic_1) Values('$folder')");
      if ($sql!=null) {


      }
      else
      {
        echo'<script>alert("notnnnn done");</script>';
      }


    }
      else{
    echo "<img src='images/img-01.png' alt='IMG'>";
      }
      ?>      </div>
```

Comment: where is your code which you have tried?

Comment: add your full code snippet not half